# Fractions ( k / p - k ) ≠ prime/prime imply gcd(k / p - k) = 1

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that for every $$k ∈ \{{ 1, 2, 3, ..., \frac{(p - \frac{1 - (-1) ^ p}{2} )}{2}}\}\E $$(E is the set of even numbers) such that $$\frac{k}{p - k} \neq \frac{prime}{prime}$$ implies that for all k of the previous set, gcd (k, p-k) = 1.

The converse is easy to prove, but I'm having trouble in this direction.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please format using MathJax, it makes it much easier to follow what you are trying to prove.

Comment: It looks like the even numbers $E$ are set-theory subtracted from something, but your notation doesn't make clear what. If anything, the set theory subtraction should be done *after* some initial set, since set theoretic subtraction is a binary operation.